# what does "as of" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does *as of* in the definition of [*severity*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/severity) given from the *Collins Dictionary* mean?

> gravity, **as of** expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As of" is identifying the context in which the word has this meaning, when there could be one or more alternative contexts. It means "as when referring to".

"Severity" means "gravity" when this word refers to a person's facial or verbal expression of seriousness. This is in contrast with the use of the word gravity to refer to the force which causes objects to fall to the ground. The latter meaning might be referred to as "as of physics".

Comment: Can you give me an example for ""gravity" when this word refers to a person's facial expression of seriousness"?

Comment: How can I read " person's facial expression of seriousness"?as person's( facial (expression of seriousness)) or ( person's facial expression) of seriousness?

Comment: @kris: Personally, I wouldn't much like, for example, *The gravity of his [facial] expression made them stop laughing*. But it might help to to note that ***expression*** can refer to *the way someone expresses themselves in words*, and I certainly have no problem with [*The gravity of his **words** stunned them into silence.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+gravity+of+his+words%22)

Comment: @kris I agree with FF, it is not limited to facial expression, so I shall edit my answer. An example is : "The severity (gravity) of his expression warned me not to ask if I could borrow his car." Personally, I don't see anything wrong with FF's example.

Comment: @kris - Those follow-on questions should be asked **in your original question**, not as extra questions under the first answer you receive.